# Degree of compositum of all number fields under given discriminant

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

For an integer $n\geq 1$ define $f(n)$ to be the degree of the compositum of all number fields with discriminant at most $n$. What bounds are known on $f(n)$?

Comment: A way to get a horrible bound would be this: you can bound the degree of the number fields involved using  the Minkowski bound and then you just need to count how many number fields of degree $k$ with bounded discriminant by $n$ are there. Best recent result due to Lemke and Thorne gives $O(n^{c(\log k )^2})$.

Comment: @VladMatei I'm not sure this is so horrible. Plugging $k = O (\log n)$ gives $e^{ O( \log n \cdot  (\log \log n)^2)}$ and now raising $\log n$ to that power gives $e^{ e^{ O ( \log n\cdot  (\log \log n)^2)}}$. On the other hand, we can obtain a lower bound of $2^{ n/\log n} = e^{ e^{ (1-o(1)) \log n}}$ just using quadratic fields.

Comment: I meant horrible because it really does not care about subfields; you are just naively multiplying the degrees out of all the possible fields.

Comment: @VladMatei "Lemke Oliver", not "Lemke".